# Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-target-audience

I am not moving forward with the facebook dev support. Therefore I was hoping that someone has experience here.

I am using the Facebook Ads API to create ads. I already rebuild the thing to create my own controllers and so on. I can see all campaigns, ad sets and ads. When creating an add I can set up parameters for targeting group.
The thing right now is that I have to specifically write strings for that. I would like to have the detailed targeting options that fb offers when choosing targeting options.

My issue is that I have no idea how to retrieve those options. I was looking for something like an array that contains those information, but all I found is a list with regions and countries. Any idea or hint that can point me to the detailed targeting options such as interests etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed targeting options are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#interests

Because the amount of options in each type is huge, the API doesn't let you list all the values. You need to search for a (part of a) phrase instead.